# Why do I need to enable Windows Developer Mode on my desktop to develop on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I am following the instructions to setup Windows 10 on my Raspberry Pi 2.

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupPCRPI.htm

Why do I need to enable Windows Developer Mode on my desktop to develop on the Raspberry Pi? Or have I misinterpreted the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy your app to RaspberryPi without "Developer Mode" enabled and it would still work.

However, when working with "Universal Apps" in Visual Studio, the XAML designer won't work if "Developer Mode" isn't enabled.